# Scale/Zoom bigger 3D models

Tags: arcore

I am currently working on ARCore for android. our use case is to load a bigger model in ARCore which is with the size of a building with more than two floors. this single big model will be extended to several floors in the building.

when we load the big model it is scaled to a smaller size by default and we could not zoom out to map/match the model for different floors. 
when we tried to set node.getScaleController().setMaxScale(50f); the model gets zoomed and hides at certain point.

```
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(fragment.getTransformationSystem());
node.getScaleController().setMinScale(0.01f);
node.getScaleController().setMaxScale(50f);
node.getScaleController().setSensitivity(0.1f);
node.setParent(anchorNode);
node.setRenderable(renderable);
node.select();
fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
```

we found a youtube link which is similar to our use case, unfortunately, this is in ARKit and by using models with .scn formats.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FG5SztPF2uY

Can someone please suggest whether this is feasible in Arcore. 
Sharing some code snippets to scale this bigger model would be very helpful.

Note: our models are in .obj formats and converted to .sfa and .sfb for using in ARCore.

Answer (score 0):

Hope after setting the max and min scale value you are using

public void setLocalScale (Vector3 scale)
Sets the scale of this node relative to its parent (local-space). If isTopLevel() is true, then this is the same as setWorldScale(Vector3).

Comment: Hi Shri, thanks for the reply!!. Yes, we are setting transformNode.setWorldScale(new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f)); but while we set the scale value more than 1.7f like setWorldScale(new Vector3(1.8f, 1.8f, 1.8f)); then some parts of the model getting disappeared.